# Confusion of JavaScript split() method

Tags: javascript, split

split method confusion

[image]

```
"aba".split("a") // ["", "b", ""]

"baab".split("a") // ["b", "", "b"]
```

Why is there an empty item in the result returned by the split method

Comment: Cause the split function was defined to work that way?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're expecting? What is the desired outcome? If you want to remve empty items then try `"baab".split("a").filter(Boolean)`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney The normal split method I understand is this “abc".split("b") // [a,c]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"aba".split("a")` gives you `["", "b", ""]` because the separator (`a`) appears at the beginning and end of the string. So conceptually there's a blank string prior to the first separator, and a blank string after the last separator.

`"baab".split("a")` gives you `["b", "", "b"]` because there's conceptually a blank string between the two separators in the middle.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> I have a question is where the blank string exists in the string.

Just prior to the separator that's at position 0.

You can find the full details, as always, in [the specfication](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.split), but [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) may be easier to read.

Consider this: If `"aba".split("a")` gave you `["b"]` instead of `["", "b", ""]`, how would you know that there were any separators in the string at all? `"b".split("a")` would also give you `["b"]`.

Comment: i was thinking there is a duplicate of the same question, but i can not find it ...

Comment: @NinaScholz - I wouldn't be surprised if you're right. I didn't check, and should have. Thanks for looking!

Comment: I have a question is where the blank string exists in the string. I can't find the relevant information. If you can reply me, I will be very grateful @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @majack - I've updated the answer. Happy coding!